Why does union distribution "collapse" during type decomposition?
Consider this common type UnionToIntersection:
type UnionToIntersection<T> =
    (T extends any ? (a: T) => void : never) extends (a: infer I) => void ? I : never;

In my understanding, the first "step" forces typescript to distribute the given union T into a corresponding union of (a: T) => void types. E.g., (a: A) => void | (b: T) => void, etc. Then, due to how TypeScript naturally handles arguments function unions, the inferred I is an intersection of T.
For example, if we have this:
type F1 = (arg: A) => void;
type F2 = (arg: B) => void;
const eitherF1orF2: F1 | F2 = (arg: any) => {}

Our eitherF1orF2 function requires the arg parameter to be A & B.
This doesn't work when we break the creation of the function union into a separate step:
type UnionOfFunctions<T> = T extends any ? (arg: T) => void : never
type UnionOfFunctionsToIntersection<T> = T extends (arg: infer I) => void ? I : never;
type UnionToIntersection<T> = UnionOfFunctionsToIntersection<UnionOfFunctions<T>>;

This decomposed version simply returns the original union.
Notably, if I combine these slightly different, it works as expected again:
type UnionToIntersection<T> = UnionOfFunctions<T> extends (arg: infer I) => void ? I : never;

Why mechanism or feature am I overlooking that causes this difference in behavior?

I didn't mean to strictly say TS "infers" the intersection, just that when TS infers the argument type, it's an intersection of A and B. Then to say that the reason for this working is due to how TS intersects function union args along the way TS distributes unions in a conditional. I'm still not sure I grok the unexpected bit to me wherein it somehow matters whether the union of functions is passed in as a generic arg or derived in place from a union in the generic arg. TLDR, I think I'm still missing something. What's the "rule" that distinguishes the two cases?

Let me back up and try again. Look at this playground link. Your type UnionOfFunctionsToIntersection<T> is a distributive conditional type because T is a bare generic type parameter, so a union in will give you a union out; there's no avoiding that.  By preventing that (wrapping with [+]) you get the intersection you expect. The rule that distinguishes them is whether it's a naked type parameter. Does that make sense?

@jcalz Ok. Seeing this example makes it click for me I think. In the "compact" one-liner form, we avoid distributing the union of functions. When I decomposed it in the first manner, my goldfish brain failed to notice that the union of functions now becomes distributed... Unless you plan to, I'll write this up as an answer later to ensure I actually understand it. Thank-you you the playground link!

I do plan to write an answer.

The difference between your two versions of UnionToIntersection is that the one with the intermediate named type alias has turned the inner conditional type into a distributive conditional type. That is, the type
type UnionOfFunctionsToIntersection<T> = T extends (arg: infer I) => void ? I : never;

will distribute over unions in T, because T is a bare generic type parameter.  So UnionOfFunctionsToIntersection<X | Y | Z> will necessarily evaluate to UnionOfFunctionsToIntersection<X> | UnionOfFunctionsToIntersection<Y> | UnionOfFunctionsToIntersection<Z> no matter what:
type Z = UnionOfFunctionsToIntersection<F1 | F2> // A | B

he infer expression never operates on a union to start with. So there's no chance for it to produce an intersection of types inferred from a contravariant position.
On the other hand, in the analogous part of the original UnionToIntersection
type UnionToIntersection<T> =
    (T extends any ? (a: T) => void : never) extends (a: infer I) => void ? I : never;

the type being checked is (T extends any ? (a: T) => void : never) which is not a bare type parameter. So it's not a distributive conditional type and it doesn't distribute over unions in that type. Therefore if it produces a union, the infer I will operate on a union and it has a chance to infer an intersection from types in a contravariant position.

To fix this so that the two versions are equivalent, you should change UnionOfFunctionsToIntersection<T> not to distribute over T. The easiest way to do that is to wrap both sides of the check in a one-tuple, like
type UnionOfFunctionsToIntersection<T> = [T] extends [(arg: infer I) => void] ? I : never;

type Z = UnionOfFunctionsToIntersection<F1 | F2> // A & B
In general, if you have a type like
type Foo<T> = Bar<T> extends ⋯ ? ⋯ : ⋯

and want to refactor it to
type Baz<T> = T extends ⋯ ? ⋯ : ⋯
type Foo<T> = Baz<Bar<T>>

and you care about union behavior, you should make sure your intermediate type is non-distributive:
type Baz<T> = [T] extends [⋯] ? ⋯ : ⋯
type Foo<T> = Baz<Bar<T>>


All of this has very little to do with the behavior of TypeScript when you try to call a union of functions, as shown in your eitherF1orF2 example:
type F1 = (arg: A) => void;
type F2 = (arg: B) => void;
declare const eitherF1orF2: F1 | F2;

declare const a: A;
eitherF1orF2(a); // error
// Argument of type 'A' is not assignable to parameter of type 'A & B'.

declare const b: B;
eitherF1orF2(b); // error
declare const ab: A & B;

// Argument of type 'B' is not assignable to parameter of type 'A & B'.
eitherF1orF2(ab); // okay

Here the argument's type is required to be the intersection of the parameters, and if you use IntelliSense to inspect the argument, you'll see that intersection.  But this doesn't translate directly to how infer works in conditional types. Yes, both behaviors involve contravariance turning unions into intersections, but they happen in different contexts. That is, the underlying type theory both features are based on is the same, but they are unrelated implementations.
Indeed, before TypeScript 3.3 introduced support for calling unions of functions, all three calls to eitherF1orF2 would fail because F1 and F2 have differing signatures. No intersection involved at all, just failure.  But the conditional type behavior introduced in TypeScript 2.8 would still infer an intersection.
So the behavior of eitherF1orF2 is sort of a red herring here; you can't really use it to conclude much about how UnionToIntersection works (or fails to work).
Playground link to code
